# JavaMail to send secure email through vps - SSLHandshake Exception, PKIX path building failed, etc. - Can't send mail

Tags: email, exception, smtp, certificate, jakarta-mail

I'm testing out sending email through my vps and I've run into a problem when it comes to sending a secure mail through SMTPS. SMTP and POP3 functions work, as the email is successfully sent. SMTPS doesn't.

I setup a simple test (JSP) page to send off an email. The code is provided below.

```
           Transport t = null; 


   try {   

      String SMTPS = "mydomainname.com";          

      String Username = "maindomainemail";
      String Password = "myhiddenpassword"; 

            InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress("mrsmith@mydomainname.com", "Bob Smith");         

         Properties props = new Properties();               

      props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");      

   props.put("mail.smtps.host", "mydomainname.com");


    String protocol = "smtps";    
    Session ssn = Session.getInstance(props, null);

       ssn.setDebug(true);            

    t = ssn.getTransport(protocol);            
    t.connect(SMTPS,Username,Password);                   

       InternetAddress to = new InternetAddress("mypersonalemail@hotmail.com", "Tom Smith");

       String subject = "testing email";

       String newBody = "message body of email";

          // Create the message
          Message msg = new MimeMessage(ssn);
          msg.setFrom(from);
          msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
          msg.setSubject(subject);
          msg.setContent(newBody, "text/html");
    t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());                  
    t.close();  

        }//try
             catch (MessagingException mex) {
              mex.printStackTrace(); }          
         catch(Exception e) {}
```

On my vps, I had to follow instructions to setup secure smtp.

After running the jsp test page, I'm getting the following exceptions in my tomcat log file.

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:11 | DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:11 | DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:11 | DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:11 | DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mydomainname.com", port 465, isSSL true
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 | DEBUG SMTP: exception reading response: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 | javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |   nested exception is:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1611)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1369)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.jsp.SendEmailViaEappsVPS_005fSMTPS_jsp._jspService(SendEmailViaEappsVPS_005fSMTPS_jsp.java:112)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:774)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:703)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:896)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 | Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:150)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1584)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:174)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:168)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:848)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:106)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:495)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:433)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:877)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1089)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:737)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:88)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1589)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  ... 26 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 | Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:221)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:145)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:203)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:172)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:320)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:841)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  ... 38 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 | Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:236)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:194)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:216)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/01/06 12:29:12 |  ... 43 more
```

What does this mean? Has anyone seen this type of exception before? What steps do I need to take to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is not finding the SSL certification, you need to manually add the host. You need to add server's certification to keystore implying it's your trusted server.

Comment: Do you feel that its necessary to send 'secure' email? Or can I just use smtp, and not smtps, and be okay?

Comment: Ideally, you should use SMTPS to avoid any man-in-the-middle attack. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack But depends on your company's policy.

Comment: Anyone know where this link now points to?  It's 404 right now :(

Comment: @GreenKiwi -- sadly, that page seem to be gone. I have posted the duplicate of that page, you may look at it here [http://cold-caffein.blogspot.com/2011/07/looks-like-article-no-more-unable-to.html](http://cold-caffein.blogspot.com/2011/07/looks-like-article-no-more-unable-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, with JavaMail 1.5.2, you can use the 'Socket Factory'-Approach as described in the official [SSLNOTES.txt](https://javamail.java.net/docs/SSLNOTES.txt):

> JavaMail now includes a special SSL socket factory that can simplify
>   dealing with servers with self-signed certificates.  While the
>   recommended approach is to include the certificate in your keystore
>   as described above, the following approach may be simpler in some cases.
>
> The class com.sun.mail.util.MailSSLSocketFactory can be used as a
>   simple socket factory that allows trusting all hosts or a specific set
>   of hosts.  For example:

```
MailSSLSocketFactory sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
sf.setTrustAllHosts(true);
// or
// sf.setTrustedHosts(new String[] { "my-server" });
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
// also use following for additional safety
//props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory", sf);
```

> Use of MailSSLSocketFactory avoids the need to add the certificate to
>   your keystore as described above, or configure your own TrustManager
>   as described below.